# Repeative Matching Group

Tags: regex

I am struggling with the following:
Change a  pattern to a "","" result.

Source:

```
Customer Number     Customer Name       Price       Group Status
100001              Test Customer       Retail      Active
```

Output:

```
"Customer Number","Customer Name","Price Group","Status"
"100001","Test Customer","Retail","Active"
```

This: `(.*?)\t` by itself will match all but the last , as there is no tab. Everything I try to capture the last group throws off the first group repetitive matching.

Comment: just split by `tab` and join with `,`  in any modern programming language. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Lookaround like this : `(^|\t)(.*?)(?=\t|$)` get the group between any (start of sentence or tab `\t`) and (tab `\t` or end of sentence)

#### regex demo

result

```
Customer Number
Customer Name
Price Group
Status

100001
Test Customer
Retail
Active
```